# Replace & to &amp; in URLs

Tags: jquery, jsp, replace, validation, ampersand

I have TONS of `XML Parsing Error: EntityRef: expecting ';'` errors on my page only because of the incorrect use ampersands in links by the developer.

Instead of asking him to use `&amp;` instead of `&`, how can I replace those after page load using jQuery?

Edit: Ah right, validators read the source so it won't work. Is there any other way to filter HTML and clear out silly errors like these?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure "the developer" isn't just you? :) Use a decent texteditor and do a "Find and replace". Or just dump XHTML and use HTML.

Comment: Yes, I'm not the developer. I like the green color on validation result page! :) This is a template file in a JSP app.

Comment: JSP? You should have told that before. Use JSTL `<c:out>` and/or `<c:url>`. It automagically escapes HTML entities and encodes URL's respectively

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: By the way, w3 validator doesn't read the original page source (would have been a security hole!). They reads the (X)HTML output, but they only doesn't run JavaScript/CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ain't going to work in Javascript, you really need to solve this at the server side.

As per the comments, you're using JSP. You can use the [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`) [`<c:out>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) and [`<c:url>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) tags for this.

The `<c:out>` by default escapes HTML entities `<`, `>`, `&`, `"` and `'`. The `<c:url>` can be used in combination with [`<c:param>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/param.html) which by default encodes query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the textual content of a page will have absolutely no effect on your validation results, as a validator does not execute scripts.  It will still see the original content of the fetched document.

If you still want to do it for reasons other than validation, you could try something like [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will not help solving validation errors. In fact, validators don't even run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to correct parse errors after the page has already been loaded and parsed. The only correct solution is to do the replacement on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could fix them in jQuery, the page is already processed by that point and the errors would still be thrown. You would be better off doing a global search for `&` and manually replacing them.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the regex for replacing & with &amp; only in links and only in the href attribute.

Comment: Thats why I said `manually` replacing them. :) I am sure there is a regex like that out there. Without knowing your editor and its restrictions I wanted to communicate the general idea of fixing it on the server.